# Next13 (app directory) push router query on client

Tags: next.js

Previously in the pages directory we could do something like this

```
router.push({
    pathname: `/employer/register`,
    query: {
        company_name: apiDataBody.company_name,
        email: apiDataBody.employer_email,
        phone_no: apiDataBody.employer_phone,
        pre_register: 'true',
    },
})
```

But now with the `next/navigation` there isn't an option to pass the any options.The only option accepted is `forceOptimisticNavigation`

Currently I have this in my code

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
      company_name: apiDataBody.company_name,
      email: apiDataBody.employer_email,
      phone_no: apiDataBody.employer_phone,
      pre_register: 'true',
}).toString();

router.push(`/employer/register?${queryParams}`);
```

Are there no in-built feature to pass the query params instead of having to construct the params manually using a URLSearchParams?

I have a helper function to help construct the search params as well

```
export function createURLSearchParams(params: {[key: string]: any}): string {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) { // Skip null or undefined values
            searchParams.append(key, value.toString());
        }
    }

    return searchParams.toString();
}
```